# Vector string replace with Julia

Tags: arrays, string, julia

I would like to find the elements of `x` which contain `"X"` and replace `"X"` with "".

```
v = split("a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p X")
x = rand(v,100) .* rand(v,100) .* rand(v,100)
```

A using a `for` loop I could:

```
for i=1:length(x)
  x[i] = replace(x[i], "X", "")
  end
```

Is this how string vector manipulation is done in Julia? Or is there a `.replace` or `apply`(`sapply(x, replace, "X", "")` as used in R) set of functions I should be using?

Comment: That's a fine way to do it. You could use `map!` to do it a bit more succinctly: `map!(s->replace(s, "X", ""), x, x)`

Comment: Keep in mind that ranges work for characters as well: `'a':'z'` is a valid range, and `string.('a':'z')` generates a vector of strings. In your particular case, because of the 'X', you need to do an extra step: `v = string.(['a':'p'; 'X'])`. Anyway, I think it's more convenient than typing out all the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```
[replace(i,"X","") for i in x]
```

But as **Stefan** pointed out in the comments, it creates a new vector.
The correct way should be (as explained by **Matt**)

```
x .= replace.(x, "X", "")
```

Just to have a quick recap of replace function, here is what the Julia official docs says.

```
help?> replace
search: replace redisplay

  replace(string, pat, r[, n])

  Search for the given pattern pat, and replace each occurrence with r. If n is provided, replace at most n occurrences. As
  with search, the second argument may be a single character, a vector or a set of characters, a string, or a regular
  expression. If r is a function, each occurrence is replaced with r(s) where s is the matched substring. If pat is a
  regular expression and r is a SubstitutionString, then capture group references in r are replaced with the corresponding
  matched text.

julia>
```

Comment: That works to produce a new vector with replacement, but it won't modify the vector of strings `x` in place.

Comment: Oh yes, @StefanKarpinski. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using for loops or comprehensions is a great solution and is typically a very performant solution. Loops are fast in Julia, so you don't need to worry about vectorizing code just to make it fast.  That said, in the upcoming 0.6 release, you can write fast vectorized code in Julia [using dot-broadcasting](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots) since strings are now treated as scalar elements in broadcast:

```
julia> replace.(x, "X", "")
100-element Array{String,1}:
 "lod"
 "kk"
 "eco"
 "jac"
 ⋮
 "ojn"
 "hmc"
 "pb"
```

You can do it in-place with:

```
x .= replace.(x, "X", "")
```